# redirect IP ranges in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I know I can deny access to an ip range in my Cpanel. For example:

`deny from 127.`

And anything starting with `127.` would be denied. How can I do something like this:

```
deny from 2.
deny from 5.
deny from 21.
deny from 57.
```

And instead of denying them, I want to redirect them to a website like www.google.com?

What could I use that would do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by putting this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(2|5|21|57)\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.com? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: to whoever 'put on hold as off topic?' don't know why. it is on topic when you do not know how to do the proper coding.

Comment: can that formula also be mixed like RewriteCond  %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} and RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(2|5|21|57)\. RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.com? [R=302,L] in same code ?

Comment: Yes definitely it can be done in same rule.